# Design Fact Table

Tags: powerbi, data-warehouse

I'm trying to design a model in PowerBi.

I've developped a model with a fact table like this.

1- SurveyFact as

```
Respondant|  Date  | Question                                  | IdResponse    | Count 
Frank    |  201801 | Where do you live      ?                 |Germany        | 1
Stephane  | 201801  | Where do you live      ?                 |France         | 1
Frank    |  201801 | What Brand is the best ?                 |Coca           | 1
Stephane  | 201801  | What Brand is the best ?                 |Pepsi          | 1
Frank     | 201801  |Does this Brand inspire quality to you ? Coca | Yes           | 1
Frank     | 201801  |Does this Brand inspire quality to you ? Pepsi| No            | 1
Stephane  | 201801  |Does this Brand inspire quality to you ? Coca | No            | 1
Frank     | 201801  |Does this Brand inspire quality to you ? Pepsi| No            | 1
Stephane  | 201801  |Does this Brand inspire quality to you ? Coca | No            | 1
Frank     | 201801  |Does this Brand inspire quality to you ? Pepsi| No            | 1
```

The difficulty I encounter is that I have to develop a report that is filtered based on the brand.

Could I create a dimension Brand in this model ??

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this based on the answer the users are giving, you need to know what is a brand question. For that I added one Column:

[image]

Next thing to do is filter by question and then select the column and take out duplicates. Add a blank query in the Editor and rename it to Brands. Open Advanced editor and past code below (be awer, you have a different source already):

```
let
    Source = Sheet1,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([BrandQuestion] = 1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{" IdResponse    "}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

Now you have a Brand Table.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now that I have my Brand table. How is the design of my table done? All my questions are not related to the brand. Can I keep in the same table?